# Same TCP/IP Port Number listed more than once in CurrPorts tool

Tags: c#, tcp, ports

I'm using C# programming in Visual Studio 2010 for creating TCP/IP ports and I'm using CurrPort tool to monitor the Port Status. After I run my program, I noticed there are two entries (listed below) for the same port# 6201 in the port monitor tool. First one with status as Listening and second with status as Established.

`TSOVista.vshost.exe    5568    TCP    6201        127.0.0.1                 0.0.0.0                              Listening

TSOVista.vshost.exe    5568    TCP    6201        127.0.0.1    50431        127.0.0.1    ST0181.stecint.local    Established`

My question is, why I'm seeing the fist one with status as Listening? As per the second one, connection is established with the host and communication is happening normally.

Could any one please help on that? Please let me know if more information is required to answer my question.

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still listening for incoming connections on that port. If you don't want to listen for new connections, close the listening socket.